# Eloquent Custom Pivot issue with belongsTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, pivot-table

I have an issue with Eloquent and L4.2

I'm trying to set a custom Pivot model below :

```
//campaign model 

public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}


public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists){
    if ($parent instanceof User) {
        return new CampaignUser($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}

//user model

public function campaigns(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('Campaign');
}


public function newPivot(Eloquent $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists){
    if ($parent instanceof Campaign) {
        return new CampaignUser($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

and below my custom pivot Model "CampaignUser"

```
public function campaign() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Campaign');
}

public function User() {
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function facture() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Facture');
}
```

Facture models has something like hasMany('CampaignUser') into method called 
campaign_user.

I'm trying to do something like :

```
> $facture->campagne_user
```

but i got this following error :

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in
>   laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
>   on line 849 and defined

Someone had this problem before ? 
How can I solve it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste the complete custom pivot CampaignUser definition ?

Comment: It's already on my previous post

Comment: UserCampaign is a pivot not a regular model so you cant use it as a relationship. It has required constructor arguments that a regular model does not.

Comment: @lagbox thank you for your answer. Is there a way to use it has a relationship or not...?

Comment: no, its not a regular model. Custom Pivot types replace the generic pivot type that is attached to models that are returned from a many to many relationship, that is it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error by trying to achieve something similar. 
Indeed you cannot use the pivot as another relation, although it inherits from `Model`, but what we can do is use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) to share the code between the *real* `Model` and the custom `Pivot`.

In your example you can place the methods defined in `CampaignUser` pivot inside a trait:

```
trait CampaignUserTrait {

    public function campaign() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Campaign');
    }

    public function User() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function facture() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Facture');
    }
}
```

Then you define a `CampaignUser` which inherits from model, and apply the trait:

```
class CampaignUser extends Model {
    use CampaignUserTrait
}
```

Next, you do the same with the custom pivot class:

```
class CampaignUserPivot extends Pivot {
    use CampaignUserTrait
}
```

Finally in your `Facture` class, just create the relationship with the `CampaignUser` which extends `Model`:

```
class Facture extends Model {

    public function campaign_user() {
        return $this->hasMany('CampaignUser');
    }
}
```

The `newPivot` method now references the new class:

```
public function newPivot(Model $parent, array $attributes, $table, $exists){
    if ($parent instanceof Campaign) {
        return new CampaignUserPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
    }

    return parent::newPivot($parent, $attributes, $table, $exists);
}
```

Basically any code that the pivot and the model share, should be in the `trait`.

I am fairly new to Laravel and PHP in general so, I don't blame anyone thinking this is a bad idea, or if a more elegant solution could exist. Moreover I haven't found any downside, but probably there are.

Greetings